# Not focusing in Talkback accessibility ModalBottomSheetLayout on launch

Tags: android, accessibility, bottom-sheet, talkback

Created a Modal Bottom Sheet. Trying to get focus when talkback is on at the launch of the Bottom sheet. It's not working. Also, When moving the focus it also focuses on the components on view behind the bottom sheet.
Any idea what's going wrong?

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun BottomSheetExample(
    contents: @Composable () -> Unit
) {

val focusRequest = FocusRequester()

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden),
    sheetContent = {
        Column {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, top = 21.dp, bottom = 21.dp),
                text = "Text Sample 1",
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.johnstonBlack)
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, top = 21.dp, bottom = 21.dp)
                    .focusRequester(focusRequest)
                    .focusable(),
                text = "Text Sample 2",
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.johnstonBlack)
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, top = 21.dp, bottom = 21.dp),
                text = "Text Sample 3",
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.johnstonBlack)
            )
        }
    },
    content = {
        contents()
    }
)
}
```

Comment: did find any solution for this?

Comment: Did not find any resolution yet so have to replace it with an activity

Comment: replace with activity ? not using compose you mean ?

Comment: I replaced it with an activity in which I am still creating the UI using Jetpack Compose. I know the purpose of using Jetpack is defeated here... but I have no option.